# React Native FBSDK file not found on CI

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

I have installed **FBSDKCoreKit**, **FBSDKLoginKit** and **FBSDKShareKit** by downloading the SDK to `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` and then dragging the frameworks in to the frameworks folder in **XCode**. I checked the option to copy the files if needed so they appear in the project.

I then added the correct framework search path `~/Documents/FacebookSDK`

Building locally works fine, however, building on Bitrise (CI) fails with the error:

> /Users/vagrant/git/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/share/RCTFBSDKShareDialog.h:21:9:
>   'FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h' file not found

The framework search path also contains `$(PROJECT_DIR)` which should find the frameworks located in `appname/Frameworks/` but I cannot seem to fix this not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/build-failing-with-file-not-found-fbsdk-in-ios-build/399/11

It seems that you have the `FacebookSDK` on your Mac at `~/Documents/FacebookSDK`, but you don't download it there on bitrise.io, so it's simply not available for your build.

Comment: How can we download and extract to bitrise?

Comment: @WitaloBenicio the way https://stackoverflow.com/a/44321452/974381 explained it (I'd suggest this solution, to include it in your repository), or via a step like https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/resource-archive which can download a ZIP file and extract it to the path you provide.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem using BuddyBuild (another CI system), and solved it via the instructions linked on their documentation page here http://docs.buddybuild.com/docs/common-react-native-errors#section-error-fbsdksharekit-fbsdksharekit-h-file-not-found, in particular this section:

> **error: 'FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h' file not found**
>
> This is generally a result of an incorrectly configured repository with
> regards to the location of FBSDK dependencies. If you take a look at:
> https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/master/ios/RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
>
> You will notice that RCTFBSDK will look for dependencies in one of two
> locations:
>
> - ~/Documents/FacebookSDK
> - $(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../ios/Frameworks
>
> The second option is the correct option for continuous integration systems
> like Buddybuild. In other words, you MUST place your FBSDK
> dependencies under the "ios/Frameworks" folder in order for it to work
> on a continuous integration system.

The problem is that as Viktor pointed out the CI system doesn't have a reference to your `FacebookSDK` folder containing the required Frameworks, so you need to actually copy the Frameworks themselves into your project itself so that everything is contained in your repository. This is necessary because the `RCTFBSDK` library expects to find the Frameworks that it requires in precisely the folder `$PROJECT_ROOT/ios/Frameworks` within your project (see the BuddyBuild documentation), and if they're anywhere else it will freak out.

For clarity the steps that I took to get my build working were:

- Create the folder `$PROJECT_ROOT/ios/Frameworks` in my project (`Frameworks` may not already exist)
- Copy the Facebook framework files from `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` into this new folder
- Reference the Frameworks in Xcode per the installation instructions on the fbsdk Github page.

Hope that this helps any future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I was using ZIP Unarchive step in Bitrise with the following path: `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` and I was not able to make it work.
When I changed the Framework Search Path to `${HOME}/Documents/FacebookSDK` I was able to continue my build with success.

Comment: `${HOME}/Documens/FacebookSDK`, I assume you mean `Documents`? That typo might trip people up a bit.

Comment: Thanks @Bataleonand